# Not linking to existing API docs but to to Docs.SO?

Tags: discussion, documentation

People start to link to Docs.SO *instead* of linking to existing, official API documentation of high quality ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38608504/1)).

I don't think this is something we should encourage. Docs.SO must not replace or overshadow existing documentation.

Comment: "must not"? I would probably soften that. Because the whole point of Docs.SO is that sometimes the official documentation sucks, and the Docs.SO copy is better. Unfortunately, I believe there are a couple of badges for linking to SO Documentation from the main site, so people are going to do it.

Comment: Somtimes, yes. But if the official documentation is of high quality, as is the case for the Python standard library, prefering Docs.SO over it is nothing I want to happen.